# Why when importing an object I only see a cross?

Tags: import

I'm trying to import an object from sketchfav, but whenever I import them, only a cross appears, I've tried to size and scale it, but nothing happens, only the cross scales. [image: crosses appear isntead of object]

Comment: try to press A to select all, then Alt S to reset the scale